# I would like to compare data between tables

Tags: oracle

I would like to compare data between two tables say source and destination and output the difference,

the problem is there's a  mapping table which stores the columns of source table and corresponding columns of destination.

For example,

Table: T_MAP

```
SourceTableName SourceTableColumns DestinationTable DestinationTableColumn

s_t1            s_t1_col1          d_t1             d_t1_col1

s_t1            s_t1_col2          d_t              d_t1_col2

s_t2            s_t2_col1          d_t2             d_t2_col1
```

....

So the question is how to compare the data between two tables with the map table.

Current idea is using dynamic cursor to generate dynamic sql statement, then using minus+union all to compare data. But the performance may be a big problem.

Is there any thoughts?

Please help..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given your current design, there's no option but to use dynamic sql. Performance may not be a problem for generating a dynamic sql statement. It will be impacted because of using cursors and loops instead of single sql. The `MINUS` query itself will take a long time if the tables are quite big. Moreover, using dynamic queries over simple sql itself poses several issues which you must be prepared with. So, an important thing to consider should be the restructuring of your whole design.

Comment: You may of course take a two step (aspetially if the mapping table is rather static). 1) generate the SQL statement for the comparison using the mapping table. 2) execute it. You must repeat the step 1) only if the mapping table is changed